# Linux system call aio_write() fails with error code 22 (EINVAL)

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, aio, aio-write

I have a testing utility that uses linux aio_write and aio_read. 
This testing utility wraps my static library and test it. This library is multi-threaded black box.

Up until now, it worked fine. But now we made a big change into the this black-box which causes the testing utility to fail as soon as it commits the first IO. 
This IO returns with errno 22 == EINVAL.

Based on the aio_write man pages, this error is issued in case one of the following fields is invalid --> *aio_offset, aio_reqprio, aio_nbytes*. 
I run it inside gdb and tested their values as long as with all other values inside the *struct aiocb ** input parameter. 
My conclusion is that the input parameters are all valid.

I suspect something has changed in the way threads are working inside the black-box. This is what i suspect causing this issue (i can not find any other explanation).

**What I really try to understand is: Which scenarios causes aio_write() to return a EINVAL error code???**

Just to clarify, when I replace the black-box to an older version, using the same testing utility it works fine.... (i also tested the input arguments here as saw they are matching to the bad version input arguments).

Comment: Try to run your program under [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace). It traces all system calls, so it'll help to understend where things have gone wrong.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer than and accept it

Comment: We where able to isolate the problem and fixed it. BUT... we do not understand the reason. 
The issue was an addition of a static Thread-Local array. Our black box uses this method, defining in several places Thread-Local variables. 
I fixed it by reducing one size and adding it to the new variable.

For example:
static __thread new old_[1024];

new code should be: 
static __thread new old_[512]; // if old_ is array of size 1024 i get the error
static __thread new new_[512];

This behavior we can not explain. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: My partner found and explenation: 
https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11787
It seems that the aio_write create a thread with small stack size and reduce from it the TLS size. So in our case the TLS size was big, therefore the aio_write thread creation failed.
In such case EINVAL value is returned.

Comment: You have questions, you have answers, you have even your conclusions, you don't need us!!! **You have posted even no lines of code.**  How do you think we are going to help you?

Comment: I had a question...
And later me and my team found a solution, therefore i posted it here as a contribute to the community in case someone else uses large TLS and aio_write and wonder why EINVAL is return as an error code. 
i do not have a relevant code to show, nor i think one is needed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the aio implementation in the linux source code at the folder `linux-kernel-source/fs/aio.c`

Sadly there are a lot of points where -EINVAL is returned. As @myaut mentioned in his comment, I recommend you to use `strace`. Another solution would be to modify the code, compile it and check where it fails.